# Design requirements for bearded dragon vivarium

Tags: reptiles, containment, bearded-dragon

I'm in the process of designing a new vivarium for a bearded dragon that I'm going to get in the future. I'm intending on building this from scratch out of high-quality materials (I'm an engineer so I know what I'm doing).

From my reading I've determined the following design requirements:

- Dimensions of at least 2 x 1 x 0.6 m.
- Must have a hot-end of roughly 37 °C.
- Must have a cold-end of roughly 26 °C.
- Must have a night-time temperature of about 21 °C.
- Must have a UVB source during the day.
- Must have hides and climbing spots.
- Humidity of around 20% is ideal.

I'm thinking of connecting all of the sensors/heaters/bulbs/misters to an STM32 board and having them all automatically controlled and maybe adding a few cameras as well so I can watch  him when I'm away.

---

My question is thus: are my requirements correct and is there anything that I've forgotten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearly everything looks good. Be aware the temperature requirements can change slightly, based on the age of the dragon. See this [relevant article](https://www.beardeddragoncare101.com/bearded-dragon-care-sheet/heating/) for more information.

Night time temperature should be slightly higher, at around 25 °C.

Humidity should be between 30-40%. It's very likely you won't need a mister to achieve this humidity. Mine naturally stays around 30%, but I spray it occasionally to raise it. I use a soil/sand mix as substrate so that likely keeps the humidity higher than tile for example would. What substrate will you be using?

I can point you to some exact products for heating/lighting if you'd like.